# Fetching all keys using the Cassandra API -- analogy to "SELECT id FROM table;"

Tags: nosql, cassandra

The Cassandra command-line utility `sstablekeys` can be used to extract all defined row keys from a physical SSTABLE file:

```
sstablekeys .../cassandra/data/Keyspace1/Standard1-N-Data.db
```

Does the Cassandra API support retrieval of all defined keys? If so, how?

I'm looking for the Cassandra analogy to `SELECT id FROM table;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [get_range_slices](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#get_range_slices)

```
list<KeySlice> get_range_slices(keyspace, column_parent, predicate, range, consistency_level)
```

which replaces get_range_slice in 0.6.

Nb. For version < 0.6: this method is only allowed when using an order-preserving partitioner.

Comment: This is allowed with any partitioner in 0.6, btw.